# InternalsVisibleTo for an entire set of assemblies possible?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to specify wildcards to give internals access to an entire set of assemblies?

Example:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("*, PublicKey="7a3c8e2f...7b3d5a62")]
```

This could allow access to all assemblies that are signed with my key, without having to specify each of my assembly names.

Is there some trick to achieve this kind of behavior?

Comment: No there isn't. [RTFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

InternalsVisibleTo is not meant to be used that way.
If you think about allowing "everyone" accessing internals, why not set public your internals ?
Maybe you question is not clear enough.

Comment: -1. He's not giving access to anyone. He's giving access to a very specific set of assemblies that have a given public key; that is a plausible scenario. Setting internal methods to public gives access to *any* assembly which is clearly not what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes, @InBetween, exactly.

Comment: I understand better, thanks InBetween

@MaDev if all assemblies are in the same solution, you could use T4 to generate the AssemblyInfo.cs